# An example of an operation in ordinary arithmetic that is idempotent

Tags: elementary-set-theory, idempotents

I came across this question in the book *Axiomatic set theory* by Suppes:

> Can you give an example of an operation of ordinary arithmetic which is idempotent?

So, here I have some things that I cannot completly understand and I need your help:

1. What is the meaning of *ordinary arithmetic*? I would understand that it means $+$ and $\times$ on $\mathbb R$, but I'm not sure.
2. Does the meaning of *an operation which is idempotent* mean for all the elements of the universe? I mean I can think of $1$ in $\times$ or $0$ in $+$ because $1\times 1=1$ and $0+0=0$, does this count?

Comment: An example comes from fixing a number $n>1$ and letting $f(m)$ be the remainder of $m$ modulo $n$.

Comment: I don't think "ordinary arithmetic" is meant as a technical term here. It probably just means something vague like "something a middle schooler would know what is".

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I'm confused. In your example it is not true that $\forall m(f(m)=m)$ as the answers suggest for the operation to be idempotent. If $n=m$ and $m\neq 0$ then $f(m)=0$. Could you help me on this?

Comment: @DanielaDiaz [Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) of a unary function $f$ means that for any $m$ in its domain, we have $f(f(m))=f(m)$. We are not requiring that $f$ is the identity. (Of course, the identity is idempotent as well.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo ya por fin le entendí, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a binary idempotent operation: $a*b=(a+b)/2$.

Answer (score 2):

$y=|x| \quad \Longrightarrow \quad |y|=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you refer to a book called *Axiomatic set theory*, I would guess that ordinary arithmetic is [Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), the first-order theory of the natural numbers with addition, but it might also be [Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).

An operation $*$ on a set $S$ is *idempotent* if, for all $s \in S$, $s * s = s$.
Two examples of idempotent operations are $\max(x,y)$ and $\min(x, y)$ on the natural numbers (or on the real numbers, if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a non empty set and $P(X)$ the power set of $X$. Union $\cup$ and intersection $\cap$ are famously idempotent operations over $P(X)$:
$$Y\cup Y =Y,\ \forall\ Y\in P(X),$$
$$Y\cap Y =Y,\ \forall\ Y\in P(X).$$

---

$\max$ and $\min$ are also well known examples of idempotent binary operations over (numeric) set $\Bbb R$.